# Will an IDisposable memory leak if you don't use a using statement?

Tags: c#, idisposable

Will an IDisposable memory leak if you don't use a using statement?
And if so, can someone provide a memory leak example if its not much code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A correctly-written program which creates an instance of a type that implements `IDisposable`, and which is not *specifically known* to be capable of adequately cleaning up after itself when abandoned, *must* ensure that `Dispose` is called on that instance before abandoning it.  Any program which fails to call `Dispose` on a type which is not specifically known to be fine without it is *broken*.

Although it would be nice if automatic finalization could take care of everything, it's a pretty crummy cleanup mechanism.  It provides no guarantees with regard to sequencing, threading context, timeliness, or certainty of completion (when using deterministic cleanup, one can make reasonably certain that a program won't appear to complete normally if cleanup fails; when using finalization, a program may appear to complete normally without even attempting to clean up an object).

Microsoft may once have intended that every `IDisposable` class should be able to adequately clean up after itself if abandoned, but that is simply not practical.  In many cases, for a class to attempt to clean up after itself if abandoned would add a massive amount of complexity, and would simply turn a broken program that would have obvious problems that are easy to track down, into a broken program that usually works except when the timing of the finalizer thread relative to some other thread causes things to fail in some unexpected and non-reproducible fashion.

There are some types which, despite implementing `IDisposable`, are unconditionally safe to abandon, and there are some others which may be safely abandoned in certain circumstances.  It is fine to abandon such types in situations where disposing them would be difficult (e.g. because references are held by multiple objects that are manipulated by various threads, and there's no nice way by which any particular object can know it when it holds the last surviving reference), provided that one documents one's reasons for believing that such action is safe and appropriate.  Such behavior is not appropriate, however, in cases where one has accepted `IDisposable` objects of unknown lineage.

Comment: We wrote answers with very closely related view points :D My up-votes are currently out, but this is spot-on.

Comment: there is an interesting case where `IDisposable` is used neither for unmanaged resource cleanup, nor for threading/reference count, but because of [security reasons](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/symmetricalgorithm.cs,61): lifetime of cryptographical keys in memory.

Answer (score 2):

No it won't leak.  Eventually garbage collection will get around to disposing the object.

`IDisposable` allows the caller to free up the resources early.

**Update**

As @Servy and @Brian Rasmussen state.  The class that implements `IDisposable` should also implement a finalizer.  This is the recommended practice.  see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: That all depends on what exactly is done in the Dispose method, and whether or not the type defined a finalizer.

Comment: If the type doesn't also provide a finalizer, it may leak unmanaged resources though.

Comment: @Servy I didn't mention a finalizer because its consedered best practice.

Comment: @RichardSchneider You say it won't ever leak and that it will always end up being handled.  That's just not true.  It's often true, but it's not *always* true.  That's a very important distinction.  Not everyone follows the best practices, so if you don't ever dispose anything your program won't just consume more of those resources, it can potentially leak them.

Comment: I agree with Servy. While "best practices" will also do Disposable-stuff in the finalizer, it is possible for external resources to be consumed *before* there is sufficient GC memory pressure/timing to invoke the finalizer.

Comment: furthermore, if you fail to dispose an IDisposable framework object now, because you checked its implementation and came to the conclusion that waiting for the finalizer is sufficient, you might still end up with a leak if that implementation changes in future framework/library/thirdpartycomponent versions.

Answer (score 2):

First off, note that *IDisposable generally relates to external unmanaged resources<sup>1</sup>* - e.g. files, connections - and leaks of such; CLR objects and memory used by such will still be handled correctly by the GC based upon reachability.

IDisposable defines a contract and represents a breaking-change when added to or removed from a type. *Any failure to honor this contract can result in "not well-defined behavior".* The `using` construct is a tool to avoid having to deal with the details of calling Dispose and edge-cases with exceptions, but it is not part of the contract and is not required. Yet, the contract remains the same and *any violations of such removes all responsibility of said IDisposable to "work correctly".*

- Some types that implement IDisposable will never leak resources; they might not dispose any external resources.
- Some types that implement IDisposable do not follow the "best practice" of also implementing a finalizer; they *will* leak external resources if Dispose is not called.
- Some types, such as those that implement the finalizer pattern as well, might only leak external resources in certain GC situations. That is, *the finalizer may not be invoked soon enough.* This condition might be too slow to be an issue in low-load scenarios but lead to unexpected failures in high-load scenarios.
- Some types might result in situations with *ill-defined behavior and inconsistent state*.

*Don't violate the contract.*

---

<sup>1</sup> An IDisposable type *could* also alter some state in Dispose that does not utilize unmanaged resources: this is still covered under "not well-defined behavior" if the contract is violated. One case where I have used an IDisposable type is to manage Runtime Callable Wrapper (RCW) objects even though they are technically "managed" by the runtime. See supercat's comment for more situations.

Comment: `IDisposable` doesn't just relate to "external" unmanaged resources; unmanaged resources can and do exist entirely within managed code.  The prime example of an unmanaged resource within managed code is an subscription to an event from a long-lived object.  If a subscriber to such an event is abandoned without unsubscribing, the subscriber's lifetime may be arbitrarily extended.  If an unbounded number of subscribers are created and abandoned during the lifetime of the long-lived object, the number of simultaneous useless subscriptions will likewise be unbounded.

Comment: Glad you like the comment.  Microsoft gives some examples of "unmanaged resource", but I've never found anywhere that it actually *defines* the term.  My definition would be that an object Foo holds a resource if some outside entity is altering its behavior on Foo's behalf, to the detriment of other entities, and will keep doing so until further notice.  A "managed resource" is a managed Object which holds a resource, and will likely clean it up, eventually, if abandoned.  Resources other than managed resources are unmanaged resources.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what your `IDisposable` is.

The `IDisposable` pattern is basically a way to deterministically release managed (and unmanaged) resources, rather than waiting until the finalizer for that object runs. If, for example, you open up database connections, file handles, etc., you will of course want these resources released or otherwise cleaned up "on demand", so they don't prevent you from re-acquiring access to them elsewhere. This is the main use case for the `Dispose` pattern.

So, will it leak memory? Again, that depends - very likely, if you're using the `IObervable<T>` subscriptions, since in one sense, they are un-released event handlers (I'm simplifying drastically here). Will you cause a memory leak if you don't close that `SqlConnection`? Not by the strictest definition of "memory leak", as the connection will close eventually (say, when your app terminates, or the connection object is finally collected and finalized), but I think I can sum all this up by saying:

**"ALWAYS dispose your IDisposables"**

EDIT: @Servy is absolutely correct - while in my `SqlConnection` example, I believe the finalizer automatically closes the connection, but this is NOT guaranteed behavior for `IDisposables` in general - so always Dispose!

Comment: This is assuming your type defines a finalizer, which it may not.

Comment: Excellent point @Servy - I may have erred a bit on the side of oversimplification.

Answer (score 1):

`using` statement just syntactical sugar

```
 using(var resource = expression) statement
```

which  translates something likes to

```
{
   var resource = expression;
   try {
      statement;
   }
   finally {
      [if(resource!=null)]((IDisposable)resource).Dispose();
   }
}
```

If dispose pattern implemented correctly the memory leak won't occurs. GC calls (non-deterministic) `Finalizer` which calls `Dispose` method.

Answer (score 0):

`Using` statement will call the object `Dispose` method at the end of the block.

you can use the following example to get the same result:

```
 obj a = new obj(); // Assuming obj : IDisposable
 try 
 {
    // Your code here
 }
 finally
 {
    if (a != null)
    { 
       a.Dispose();
    }
 }
```