# Do I really need to call Dispose() on every Principal?

Tags: .net, resources, dispose, iprincipal, groupprincipal

I'm doing some Active Directory work with .NET's `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace. I noticed that `Principal` implements `IDisposable`, which causes sort of a headache since *everything* in that namespace inherits `Principal`.

E.g. consider the following code to get all the users in a group:

```
PrincipalContext domain = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domain, "MyGroup");
PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> users = group.GetMembers();
```

Every single type in that snippet implements `IDisposable`, including all the users returned by the search and the search result set itself.

Disposing of the `domain` and `group` objects is not a big deal (it would be easy with a `using()` block), but what do I do about every result? Do I really have to loop through that `users` collection and dispose of every one?

Comment: FWIW, [GroupPrincipal.GetMembers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339975.aspx) shows only the group being disposed. I can't find any documentation (yet) that explicitly states this contract of "member lifetime ownership": +1 because I do find this particular contract (or perhaps lack thereof), interesting. However, here is my [general view on the IDisposable contract](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14781766/166390).

Comment: Here's an answer that may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14627265/2258

Answer (score 4):

The `IDisposable` contract is just that, a contract.  It's expected to be followed.  They wouldn't have implemented the contract had you not "need to call Dispose"...

In reality, you can't really tell what type of object is being used by a particular instance of `Principal`  Sometimes, you *do* have to dispose it, sometimes you *don't*.  You really don't have a way of telling at runtime unless you know some of the internals of a particular implement of `Principal`.  For example, if the underlying object in the Principle instance is a `DirectoryEntry`, then you should dispose it.  But, you have not real way to tell at run time what that underlying object is.  Even if you *could*, it would seem easier to simply call `Dispose`.

Comment: Right, I know that everything needs to be disposed. I just feel like it's confusing what I'm "in charge of". My usual assumption is that if I instantiate an object I'm responsible for cleaning it up, but that obviously doesn't apply to these classes. The MSDN docs are totally unhelpful: most of their samples have no `Dispose()` calls at all.